# Take screen shot , upload and tweet on titanium

Tags: titanium

I am making application on iOS and Android on Titanium.

What I want to do is

1) take screen shot

2) upload pics

3) post tweet including pics link

What I have done so far is.

1)I can take screenshot like this and save the photo in camera folder

```
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e){
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
});
```

2)I have no idea about that

3)I can tweet with social.js

```
   var social = require('social');
    var twitter = social.create({
        site : 'Twitter',
        consumerKey : '*',
        consumerSecret : '*' 
     });
     twitter.share({
        message : data,
        success : function() {
           Ti.API.info('Tweeted!');
        },
        error : function(error) {
           Ti.API.info('You have already shared this app on Twitter.');
        }
    });
```

Currently I am trying to do on twitter however I would like to make for android version.

---

Thank you for the comment of @turtle.

I found I need to use Social_plus.js.

I have changed the code like this below

```
var social = require('/myfunc/social_plus');

var data = new Object();
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e){
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
    data['image'] = e.media;
});
data['text'] = 'lets tweet!!';

var twitter = social.create({
    site : 'Twitter',
    consumerKey : '*',
    consumerSecret : '*' 
     });
twitter.shareImage({
    message : data['text'],
    image : data['image'],
    success : function() {
        Ti.API.info('Tweeted!');
    },
    error : function(error) {
        Ti.API.info('Somehow error!.');
    }
});
```

However, I got the error like this .

```
[ERROR] :  Social.js: FAILED to send a request!
[INFO] :   You have already shared this app on Twitter.
[ERROR] :  {"errors":[{"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter."}]}
c
```

I guess there is something wrong with the sentene

```
data['image'] = e.media;
```

But I can't find good information around here.

Comment: For 2/ upload pics **where** ? If on twitter maybe [this answer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153811/image-sharing-on-twitter) will help

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I can make progress. i have updated the article.